# Uncountability of the set of binary sequences

Tags: real-analysis

All the proofs of uncountability of the set of binary sequences that I could find rely on Cantor's diagonalization argument. I was wondering if my solution, that I describe below, is correct.

The set I am interested in is
$$S = \{(s_i)_{i\geq 0}: s_j = 0 \text{ or } s_j = 1 \text{ for all } 0 \leq j <\infty \text{ with } j \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

What I want to show is that $S$ contains at least as many elements as the real numbers in the interval $(0,1)$. The mapping $f: (0,1) \mapsto S$ that I propose is as follows. Let $0<x<1$ be represented as $x=0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$. Then
$$f(x) = 00\ldots 010\ldots010\dots$$
where the first $1$ appears at the $(a_1+1)^{th}$ digit, the second $1$ appears at the  $(10+a_2+1)^{th}$ digit and so on.
Clearly, I can represent any real number in $(0,1)$ in this form but the set $S$ has more elements than the range of $f$. So then I conclude $S$ must be uncountable. Would this constitute an acceptable proof (if it is a proof at all)?

Comment: As long as you are given that the interval $(0,1)$ is uncountable. One merit of the diagonalization proof is that it does not rely on such assumptions.

Comment: But then you need to prove that the set of real numbers in (0,1) is uncountable. And this is usually derived from uncountability of the set of binary sequences, so, if you use that proof, you get circular reasoning.

Comment: Yeah, I think that works. You need to have proven $(0,1)$'s uncountability first, but it works.

Comment: You have to be a little more careful, since, for instance, $0.5=0.4999\ldots$, and your map takes the two representations to different sequences. However, you can agree beforehand to use the terminating representation in such cases. With that proviso, however, it works, provided that you already know that $(0,1)$ is uncountable.

Comment: The set of infinite sequences of $0,1$ is usually denoted by $\{0,1\}^\omega$ or $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$, by the way. (The reason being that a sequence $s_n$ can be thought of as a function $s:\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$, and $A^B$ means the set of functions from $B$ to $A$ in set theory.)

Comment: @Litho Can't I use a function like $f(x) = \log{x}$ combined with the observation that the non-positive  real line is uncountable (which relies on the entire real line being uncountable)?

Comment: @Calculon But how do you prove that the real line is uncountable?

Comment: @Calculon Yeah. Showing that $\mathbb R$ and $(0,1)$ are uncountable is basically the same thing.

Comment: @Litho In the book that I am following it is done using the Nested Intervals Property, which is almost axiomatic.

Comment: @Calculon If you use that proof of uncountability of $\mathbb{R}$, then your proof is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can employ the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem to show there is a bijection from S to (0,1).(I have one book that calls it Schroeder-Bernstein, another that calls it Cantor-Bernstein): If there exists a 1-to-1 function from A into B and a 1-to-1 function from B into A then there is a bijection from A to B. The proof is simple but I wouldn't call the idea in it "obvious". Now,to map S, 1-to-1 into (0,1) let $f((s_n)_{n\in N})= 1/3 +\sum _{n \in N} s_n3^{-n}$.To map (0,1), 1-to-1 into S, let $g(x)=(s_n)_{n\in N} \in S$, when [ $x= \sum _{n\in N}s_n2^{-n}$ and $s_n=0$ for infinitely many $n$].